# PHP: mysqli clearing stored results

Tags: php, mysqli

I was using this function to clear stored results after calling a procedure etc.

```
function clearStoredResults($mysqli_link){
#------------------------------------------
    while($mysqli_link->next_result()){
      if($l_result = $mysqli_link->store_result()){
              $l_result->free();
      }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the following message/error

> mysqli::next_result(): There is no next result set. Please, call
>   mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call
>   this function/method in

If I change `next_result()` to `more_results()` the page keeps loading for a while and I get a time out error:

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use both methods:

```
function clearStoredResults($mysqli_link) {
#------------------------------------------
    while($mysqli_link->more_results()) {
         $mysqli_link->next_result();
         if($l_result = $mysqli_link->store_result()) {
              $l_result->free();
         }
     }
}
```

Use `more_results` to control the loop, and `next_result` to actually move the cursor.

Comment: @js091514 Thanks; I know it wasn't you, but somebody downvoted it for no apparent reason.